# Grabbing QUERY values .. using GET

Tags: php

I have a php page (index.php) that is being used as a 'go-between' to serve up the filename being passed in the URL/query string..

the URL is like so:
/index.php?filename=xxxxxxx

Using this code:

```
//check file type being asked for:
if (isset($_GET['filename'])) { 
    if (strpos($filename, '.pdf') == FALSE){
        echo "TYPE: .pdf";
    }else{
        echo "TYPE: other";
    }
}
```

it works fine...

but now I have a URL like this:
/index.php?filename=xxxxxxx?catalog=yyyyyyy

When I echo out the filename.. it shows the WHOLE thing.. (meaning even the catalog value too)

(which I guess is fine by default).. but I'd ALSO like to be able to pick out both pieces separately..

trying to grab the catalog query var, yields nothing:

```
if (isset($_GET['catalog'])) {  
    echo "Catalog ID: " . $_GET['catalog'];
    echo "Catalog ID: " . $catalog;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or missing in the bigger picture here?

(I also cant seem to add in any \n or \r's to my echo statement, everything is on one line?)

Thanks to anyone with some adice/suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET Parameters should be divided with & and not ?.

So your URL should be like:

`/index.php?filename=6085f6a87b674879a0224a854a3585c21d&catalog=7711f660-4fa7-4236-afd1-0704fc2a2356`

Comment: HAHA..  OMG!.. what a 'duh' moment!

Thanks!  (marked as correct though none the less!)  LOL

Comment: Lol. Its OK. We all get confused sometimes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple GET parameters should be separated by an ampersand, not a question mark.